# Bind a combo box inside a data context to a first-level list in class

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, data-binding

I have these two lists on my class :

```
public ObservableCollection<string> List1{ get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> List2{ get; set; }
```

And I want to bind them to this list box:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List1}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,6" />
                    <ComboBox Width="70" ItemsSource="{Binding List2} SelectedIndex="0" />   
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

In a way that the textblock of each item will be the item of List1 and each combo box will have the List2 items as options. I don't want to create a second-level relationship because the items of List2 will change frequently and I don't want to have to update each list individually.

Comment: Whats the question here, does the binding of the second list not work? Are the two lists declared in a Viewmodel, and how did you set the Window's `DataContext`?

Comment: The problem was that the binding of the List2 didn't work. Pragmateek's answer solved it though, by using relative binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a relative binding:

```
<ComboBox Width="70" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.List2,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" SelectedIndex="0" />
```

Comment: When debugging the binding works fine. When not, though, I get an object reference not set to an instance error.
Could this be due to the fact that the collection is initiallized in the constructor, and how do I get rid of it?
Or should I just ignore it cause it doesn't affect the runtime at all?

Comment: Binding errors are not critical because the binding engine expects that some values are not available right now but will be in the future. Initializing the `ObservableCollection`s to empty collections instead of `null` references should fix the issue.